# Rails 3.2+ best practice for using Haml to generate Javascript templates (JST)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, haml, asset-pipeline, jst

I asked a specific question about problems I'm having with a specific gem intended to do this in a separate thread ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577033/1206117?sem=2 )

But I feel I may be on the "wrong boat" somehow because all of the questions I find about Rails/Haml/JST-templates are at least 2 years old, or go unanswered.

I'm writing an app with a lot of client-side JS and so want to use templates to render views (I'm using Backbone).  I want to use Haml to write the templates.

I'm not looking for a debate about which gem/method is better, I'm looking for A WAY that works and has current support and active use.  At present I cannot write my JS templates in Haml, and it's a bummer.  I'm avoiding CoffeeScript at present since I'm still rather new to Javascript.

Comment: I'd prefer not to add yet another language that is *sort of* like one I'm already using.  Since I'm using Haml for server-side html generation, I'd like to do the same for my JS templating if possible...

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted an issue to the haml git repo.

https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/716

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets gives you what you want. (`window.JST` templates, written in HAML, with inline coffescript support)